# Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor) Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, macos, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, vscode-remote

When using VSCODE 1.43 w/ remote-ssh I am unable to access a RHEL7 server and get the following error message:

````
[12:52:12.322] > Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
> Thus no job control in this shell.
[12:52:12.562] stderr> stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[12:52:12.564] stderr> stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[12:52:12.590] stderr> stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment from the thread Colby linked states that a good general workaround for this issues is to set the `remote.SSH.useLocalServer` setting to `false`. This way lets you use the most recent version of the remote-ssh extension.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2527#issuecomment-599712180

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2527

From this thread, it appears that downgrading the "Remote - SSH" extension to 0.49 is the best temporary fix. It worked for me.

To downgrade, click "Manage" on the "Remote - SSH" extension and select "Install Another Version...", choose 0.49.0 from the list of versions.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i use "ssh fs" extension

"remote - ssh" work on my linux server from my windows client and my linux client, and also work on my freebsd server from my windows client,
but doesnt work when on my freebsd server from my linux client

so i change the vsc extension to "ssh fs" from kelvin schoofs
and it works